# Fancybox - set widths for different overlays

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a several blocks of content which open in a Fancybox. This all works as it's meant to but the contents of a couple of the boxes is quite small and doesn't really warrant a 1000px width Fancybox overlay. Is there a way to set the widths of these boxes to something else?

I've tried added a width to the content box (#login-overlay) for example but Fancybox just ignores this as it is built around the content once the relative link has been clicked which opens the overlay.

Here's my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        margin: [20,20,20,20],
        padding: [20,20,0,20],
        openEffect: 'fade',
        openEasing: 'easeInQuad',
        openSpeed: 400,
        title: false,
        //closeBtn: false,
        //autoCenter: false,
        scrolling : 'no',   // turns off scrolling in box.
        fitToView : false,  // allows box to overflow out of viewport.
        autoSize: false,    // needs to be turned off for width/maxWidth to work.
        height: 'auto',     // if autoSize is set to 'false', this needs to be 'auto' so height matches content.
        width: '100%',
        maxWidth: 960,
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                // locked: false, // Prevents jump to top of window when opening a fancybox.
                showEarly : false
            }
        },
        tpl: {
            closeBtn : '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close icon-circle-cross" href="javascript:;"><span>Close</span></a>'
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see I'm using `maxWidth` to see the width of the default size. I couple of boxes could be almost half that. I've tried setting `auto` so see if it would inherit the width set on the content block in the CSS but this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas that don't involve writing a whole need block of script for `$(".fancybox-narrow")`?

**EDIT**
I actually found an example on the Fancybox page which uses `data-fancybox-width` to set the width of an overlay: http://jsfiddle.net/wgPTR/

Though this doesn't seem to work with my code. The width sets but it isn't responsive anymore. Setting `fitToView` to `false` seems to get that working but then the fancybox crops when there's not enough vertical space and it's un-scrollable.

**UPDATE**

Just to update, here's a CodePen of the working (default) fancybox: http://codepen.io/moy/pen/YGgjqv

I've also created a forked version which uses `data-fancybox-width` to set a width - which works but unfortunately the fancybox is no longer responsive. The only way to get this to work is to take out `fitToView: false` which breaks my vertical scrolling.

Any ideas?

Comment: usually using auto size will fit the frame to the size of it's content.  Are you sure you do not have some sort of width set on the content that is being loaded.  eg a min width on the bodyor containing div  or something like that

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had a play around with `autoSize` but as the content in the overlay is text it becomes a bit squashed. I suppose I could do with 2 `maxWidth` settings in a way. I don't have any widths set on content in the CSS. I did try setting some widths to see if Fancybox would inherit/use them but it didn't work well responsively.

Comment: Just remove the `height` and set `autoSize` to `true` http://jsfiddle.net/6L2Ldo8m/

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately if you resize your browser the overlay doesn't shrink with it. That's the problem I'm having too :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found a solution (with a lot of help from the CSS Tricks forum) by using the following `beforeLoad` if statement:

```
beforeLoad: function() {
    if ($(this.element).hasClass('fancybox--small')) {
        this.maxWidth = 600;
    }
}
```

Basically it checks for the class `fancybox--small` and if it's present it amends the `maxWidth` of the fancybox.

Can't see any problems with it (yet), checking in IE it seems to work down to IE8 as well. Hopefully this helps someone else but let me know if you find any issues with it ;)